# What does Annie's father tell her?

Tags: attack-on-titan

**What does Annie's father tell her in the flash backs in *Attack on Titan*?**

If possible, answer this question without material from Season 2

Comment: As far as i know, Annie's father tells her that at all costs she has to "carry out the plan" in the flashbacks. The plan is not revealed yet, but whatever it is, it has to be carried out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her father says to her that he will not ask for her forgiveness after everything that has happened.

Instead, he requests that she should always remember that, even if she makes the whole world her enemy, her father will always be on her side.

Picked off from: [Chapter: Wall](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_(Chapter))